# Can I open a certain website with a command line?

Tags: command-line

I am configuring hotkeys for commands and want a way to open websites from the command line.

For example, how would I open YouTube directly in Firefox without *first* opening the browser and *then* entering the address for YouTube?

Comment: `links2 https://jadi.gitbooks.io/lpic1/content/
`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the command

`firefox http://www.youtube.com`

This should do it. 8 )

Comment: that did it!! just had to restart firefox. Thx :D

Answer (score 20):

Have a look at `xdg-open` which uses the default program for opening the link:

```
xdg-open http://example.com
```

some documentation from Ubuntu:

[xdg-open - opens a file or URL in the user’s preferred application](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you only need to open it in the background use:

```
wget http://askubuntu.com
```

To download a page (optionally mirror sub pages):

```
wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P ~/Desktop/ http://askubuntu.com/users/182026/kamil
```

If you want to open it and see it

and you use firefox:

```
firefox http://askubuntu.com
```

or you use google chrome

```
google-chrome http://askubuntu.com
```

Comment: oh that's a nice trick. thx a lot :D

Comment: I just tried it, but it doesn't work...

Comment: @ubuntu.stuff which one doesn't work for you?

Comment: well the very top one. wget does not do anything...

Comment: Indeed, it does, but you're not seeing what happened. do you want to save the page?

Comment: @ubuntu.stuff check my edit

Comment: what do you mean, save the page? what I want is that I hit a button and youtube opens, minimized, so that when I click on firefox youtube has already opend

Comment: @ubuntu.stuff I mean download for offline reading

Comment: wget has problems  on my side, with  `https` ...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the web page from an xterm/command line then you can install lynx on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have lynx-cur installed.

```
apt-get install lynx-cur
```

I don't think you need any special repositories,

```
lynx http://askubuntu.com
```

I use it to do screen scrapes

```
wget can be used as follows if you want to look at what is going by:

wget -O- -S http://askubuntu.com | more
```

This will send the output to stdout, and give you the server-response info